# HTML5 postMessage - multiple on message handlers, same page, what happens?

Tags: javascript, html, events, messaging, postmessage

I have a parent page "A" which embeds an iFrame "B".  They are not on the same domain.

Parent window "A" posts to frame "B" that we would like to login.  Frame "B" receives the message, and kicks off Google's OAuth 2.0 flow (javascript).

Frame "B", as part of the authentication workflow, calls a method - gapi.auth.authorize( params, callback );

This method, embedds a frame, "C", into frame "B", and registered ANOTHER message handler.  Now, we have two message handlers on the same page (B).  First, we have the $(window).on("message", fnc) handler that we wrote, but then now we also have a handler from the google api, which talks to it's iFrame (C).

This is causing problems, and confusion.  When a message arrives at B - what happens?  Who gets it?

For clarity - Here's the code for the message handler sitting in frame "B".

```
$(window).on('message', function(e) {

          // make sure the origin is what we want.  we LOSE google's events here!
          if ( isSafe( e.originalEvent.data ) ) {
                // do stuff
          }

});
```